# elasticsearch search text return full array issue

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using **mongoosastic** for **elasticsearch**. and i done all setup and its working fine. but problem is result are not getting properly.

**FILE:- mongoose and mongoosastic.**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var medicineSchema = require('./search')
var mongoosastic = require("mongoosastic");

var UserProfileSchema = new Schema({
    userId: String,
    username: String,
    address: String,
    number: Number,
    task: [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            es_boost: 2.0 // or es_indexed:true
        },
        taskCode: String,
    }]
});
UserProfileSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);
UserProfileSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 9200,
    //  ,curlDebug: true
});
UserProfile = module.exports = mongoose.model('UserProfile', UserProfileSchema);
UserProfile.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('mapping created!');
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});
```

And my search Query:

```
var UserProfileSchema = require('../../app/models/user');
 UserProfileSchema.search({
        query_string: {
            query: name
        }
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '-1',
                MESSAGE: 'System error'
            });
        } else {
            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '1',
                DATA: result
            });
        }
    });
```

Now my problem is if  **task** array has 3 object and when i search for task string i.e "abc" it will return full collection. with all task **But i want only searched string object from  task array.** i.e name :abc object

*......*

```
"task" [{
    name: 'abc',
    taskCode: 123
},{
    name: 'xyz',
    taskCode: 123
},{
    name: 'cdx',
    taskCode: 123
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The good thing is that your `task` field is already of type [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) in your schema, which is a pre-condition for achieving what you expect.

Now in order to achieve what you want you need to use [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) in your query.

```
UserProfileSchema.search({
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "task",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "task.name": name
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}        <--- this does the magic
    }
  }
}, ...
```

Comment: can i write this type of query in **query_string: { query: name}** as i given in example. because i tried **match in   query_string ** it return error

Comment: Try replacing your whole query in `UserProfileSchema.search` with the above query.

Comment: sure i will try now and let you know please help me i spend lot of time for this.

Comment: in console of elasticsearch it will peint error failed to parse source and my query in array [ query........]

Comment: What version of ES are you using? `inner_hits` was added in 1.5.0. Maybe you can update your question with the output you're getting. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32294267/4696809 see now i am using curl request directly to test but it want work and i am using "lucene_version" : "4.10.4" and elastic verion number is  : "1.7.1",