# Elasticsearch full-text query issue from inner array

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, full-text-search, mongoosastic

This is my object. and I want find text inside of task i.e **task.name.**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55e2acd77e5e4ddc037b3ef5"),
  "userId" : "123",
  "username" : "user12",
  "address" : "abc",
  "number" : 928228828282.0,
  "task" : [{
      "name" : "metac",
      "productCode" : "1234",
      "_id" : ObjectId("55e2acd77e5e4ddc037b3ef7")
    }, {
      "name" : "alfa33",
      "productCode" : "1234",
      "_id" : ObjectId("55e2acd77e5e4ddc037b3ef6")
    }],
  "__v" : 0
}
```

so when I query for that it will return all task.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/userprofiles/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match": { "name": "alfa33" } }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "took": 51,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.19178301,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "userprofiles",
                "_type": "userprofile",
                "_id": "55e2acd77e5e4ddc037b3ef5",
                "_score": 0.19178301,
                "_source": {
                    "userId": "123",
                    "username": "user12",
                    "address": "abc",
                    "number": 928228828282,
                    "task": [
                        {
                            "name": "metac"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "alfa33"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see task return full array I want only 1 task which is selected.

I am using mongoosastic inside node it will give me problem so i tried to use request directly to Elasticsearch.

mongoosastic  config - >[elasticsearch search text return full array issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32288175/4696809) i tried this solution but not working.

Currently I am search my result using curl command in git bush not using search function

EDIT

**FILE:- mongoose and mongoosastic.**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var medicineSchema = require('./search')
var mongoosastic = require("mongoosastic");

var UserProfileSchema = new Schema({
    userId: String,
    username: String,
    address: String,
    number: Number,
    task: [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            es_boost: 2.0 // or es_indexed:true
        },
        taskCode: String,
    }]
});
UserProfileSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);
UserProfileSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 9200,
    //  ,curlDebug: true
});
UserProfile = module.exports = mongoose.model('UserProfile', UserProfileSchema);
UserProfile.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('mapping created!');
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});
```

And my search Query:

```
var UserProfileSchema = require('../../app/models/user');
 UserProfileSchema.search({
        query_string: {
            query: name
        }
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '-1',
                MESSAGE: 'System error'
            });
        } else {
            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '1',
                DATA: result
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add at least the code you use to retrieve it

Comment: @Michelem i given link of my code in question then also i update my question again

Comment: @Michelem  i am creating  default mapping as you can see in code

Comment: I think this query is correct, look at `"hits": { "total": 1, ...}`, this means it found user with task, but user has other tasks also, Query returned user, not task itself, If you want to get only Task, then make handler for Task API, currently you are hitting `localhost:9200/userprofiles/_search?pretty`, make API for `localhost:9200/tasks/_search?pretty` for example

Comment: @evc ohh yes you are right.

Comment: @KevalBhatt should i add answer or you will delete this question?

Comment: @evc please add answer i am trying but don't understand how to do create different api of nested object. please help me i am trying this fom last 2 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to treat these as separate objects, you will need to use a nested type
for the "task" field, so setting up your mappings as follows:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "... all the other fields ...": {},
            "task": {
                "properties": {
                    "_id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "productCode": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After reindexing your document. You'll need to use a nested query with an
inner-hits query to return which task matched the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "task",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "alfa33"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The `inner_hits` portion will return the specific task that matched the query by
itself.

I've posted an example with the
[full output here](http://writequit.org/org/es/#nested-inner-hits) since it's a
little long to post in entirety here.

Comment: i will try this example. and let you know if i am facing any problem.

Comment: ... all the other fields ...  means my parent object  right ?

Comment: That is the other fields, like userId, username, address, etc